# Is there a kill-switch-like solution that will remotely redirect the domain to a subfolder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, redirect

I'm looking into kill switch alternatives. The people I'm working with don't like that the [css kill switch](http://csskillswitch.com/) makes the screen black and have asked for a kill switch that remotely redirects to a subfolder once activated. So when the kill switch is activate on our server the kill switch will redirect from www.domain.com to www.domain.com/oldsite/ which will hold their old site files. Is there a solution like this?

Comment: Do you mean a technique that will, like the CSS kill switch page you link to, work by letting you kill a client's site even though you no longer have access to their servers? (Or in your case not so much "kill" as "redirect".)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same trick they're using, but with JavaScript.

First, in the head of their document, add this link to a JavaScript file on your server:

```
<script src="http://your-server.com/kill-switches/offending-site.js"></script>
```

Then, in your server's root, create a folder with the name `kill-switches`. In there, create a file named `offending-site.js`, and put this in that file:

```
window.location = 'http://offending-site.com/oldsite';
```

Then, just comment/uncomment that line as need.

---

**Note:** Keep in mind that this is as *un*foolproof as the CSS Kill Switch. Your client could just remove that `script` line and be done with it.

**P.S.** Be sure to serve non-caching headers, or it won't work.

Comment: As a side note, is there actually fool proof way to do this?

Comment: _"is there actually a fool proof way to do this?"_ - Not if you don't have access to the server(s) where the code is deployed.